# Unity ads set focus back to Unity after display (?)

Tags: unity-ads

How do you have Unity ads set its focus back to Unity after being displayed?

Launching Unity ads seems to take the focus away from the Unity app! – The user has to manually touch/click the app to move the focus back to the unity app after launching and watching a unity ad

Comment: What specific part of your Unity app do you want to switch the focus to?

Comment: Launching Unity ads seems to take the focus away from the Unity app!

Comment: Basically the user has to manually touch/click the app to move the focus back to the unity app after launching and watching a unity ad

Comment: On what platform(s)?

Comment: Unity iOS - last few versions